# Merge model with extensible record in Elm 0.19

Tags: merge, record, elm

I define an extensible record

```
type alias Saved a =
  { a
    | x : Int
    , y : String
  }
```

and a `Model` based on that:

```
type alias Model =
  Saved { z : Float }
```

I then load and decode JSON into a `Saved {}`:

```
let
  received =
    Decode.decodeValue savedDecoder json |> Result.toMaybe
in
(Maybe.map
  (\r ->
    { model
    | x = r.x
    , y = r.y
    }
  )
  received
  |> Maybe.withDefault model
```

Is there any way to merge the existing `model` with the `received` extensible record that does not involve copying each field individually, similar to the ES6 `Object.assign` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the way it's done. Optionally, you can pattern match a parameter:

```
Maybe.map
  (\{x, y} ->
    { model
    | x = x
    , y = y
    }
  )
```